# What are the differences between the hardcover versions of V for Vendetta?

Tags: dc, comics, v-for-vendetta

DC is publishing a new hardcover version of V for Vendetta, called the [30th Anniversary Deluxe Edition](https://www.vertigocomics.com/graphic-novels/v-for-vendetta-1988/v-for-vendetta-30th-anniversary-deluxe-edition). From the description on the DC website it is difficult to know if this version is similar, adds or lacks content compared to the existing [Absolute](https://www.vertigocomics.com/graphic-novels/v-for-vendetta-1988/absolute-v-for-vendetta) hardcover version.

Since the new version hasn't come out, it might be a long shot to ask this, but does anyone have any information about this new version and how it compares to the existing one?

Comment: Your question is being closed because it reads like a shopping question. I don't think it actually is off-topic. If you edited it slightly to ask if there's any differences between the two books that would be on-topic.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I'll edit

Comment: Googling suggests they will be identical and this is just a re-release. But nothing concrete in terms of evidence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [V for Vendetta 30th Anniversary edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1401285007) contains;

> ...DC Comics'
> original 10-issue series in its entirety, including the "bridging"
> pages colored by David Lloyd, which originally ran between the issues'
> story pages. This deluxe volume also includes Lloyd's and Moore's
> introductions to the series as well as Moore's extended history of its
> creation, "Behind the Painted Smile," and an expanded sketchbook
> section by Lloyd.

As compared to the [V for Vendetta: Absolute Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1401223613) which has

> This new edition features the improved production values and coloring
> from the 2005 hardcover in larger format for optimum enjoyment of the
> stunning art and story [and] includes the original 10 issues plus
> never-before-reprinted bridging pages which are newly colored, plus
> intros by Lloyd and Moore to the series plus Moore's extended history
> of its creation "Behind the Painted Smile" and a newly expanded
> sketchbook section by David Lloyd.

As best as I can tell, there are no fundamental differences between the two editions, other than that the Absolute edition has a hard slip case and a different cover as well as a few additional sketches.